# Writing extensions for VsCode: watch task

Tags: javascript, plugins, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Apologies if this question has been already asked and if my analysis is lacking in comprehension of the matter: I'm just starting with VsCode so It's highly possible that I'm heavily lacking of the necessary knowledge.

I've spent short of 8 full hours googling around and reading the Vscode documentation but I cannot seem to find a single example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

I'm trying to write a simple plugin using Js (instead of TypeScript). The problem I'm facing is that I want to write ES6 code using ES Modules instead of commonjs ones (in short: I want to use `import/export` in my extension code, instead of `require()/exports.xxx`

In order to do so, what I understood is that I've to configure my extension to use a `preLaunchTask` that compiles and watch my code for changes (recompiling it again into common js code).

I've looked at the extension code generated for a typical TypeScript extension (since it has the same compilation and watch steps) and I tried replicating it using babel compile and watch, but to no avail.

There are many undocumented (or not explained properly) properties around the `tasks.json` file and it's really getting frustrating, so I'm asking for help from the community before I give up and decide to go back to Emacs or manually recompile (Ctrl+Shift+B) every time I make changes to my code...

So, what I'm trying to do is just to setup an extension using ES6 modules (the extension just says "Hello World" atm, I'm focusing on setting up a proper dev environment).

My .vscode/launch.json looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Extension",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "watch-and-compile"
        },
    ]
}
```

I'm not even sure what value should I give to`preLaunchTask`, so what I tried is to give it a value that will match the `label` property in my task in `tasks.json`. It seems to run it, so I guess it's ok.

Now, down to the `tasks.json`:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [{
    "label": "watch-and-compile",
    "command": "npm",
    "args": [ "run", "watch"],
    "type": "shell",
    "isBackground": true,
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch"
  }]
}
```

From the scarce documentation available on "problemMatcher" I didn't get any real idea of what that is.. so I used the value that I've seen used for the transpiling process used by tc when converting (and watching changes on) TypeScript files.  I've seen this matcher used in a Gulp extension somewhere so I guess it might work as a sort of "category" for vscode to understand what type of processing work the task is performing but, again, I've not a real clue on how things are supposed to work and I'm finding the whole process incredibly frustrating, considering that all of this is BEFORE even starting to actually write the logic of my extension.

My code, as it stands now, seems to launch my task correctly but it `hangs` (since `npm run watch` is actually a blocking process, watching for changes to the files and recompiling them on the fly). using `isBackground` doesn't seem to accomplish anything, since the process doesn't appear to run in the background at all. when I launch my debugging session for my extension, the task runs and blocks the entire process from progressing further... only when I kill the process in the terminal then the debugger moves on and load and activate my extension in the new Vscode debugging window.. so there's definitely something I'm missing here

Can some good soul step in and guide me in the right direction here?  I'm just trying to get to the point where I can write my extension code using ESM, that's it.

Thanks in advance for any help/advice/tip on the matter!

Comment: I have no answer, but you might get some insights from looking at the source code of [generator-code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-code)